# Hibernate C3P0ConnectionProvider not picked up

Tags: java, hibernate, c3p0

I am trying to configure C3P0 connection pool for my hibernate application.

I am using below dependencies.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.6.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.6.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

I added below configs in my `hibernate.cft.xml`

```
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">5</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">1800</property>
```

But I get the warning below:

```
WARN: HHH000022: c3p0 properties were encountered, but the c3p0 provider class was not found on the classpath; these properties are going to be ignored
```

If I explicitly specify the provider class like given below, it works.

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
```

But the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/c3p0/internal/C3P0ConnectionProvider.html) of the above class says it should be picked by default.

> A connection provider that uses a C3P0 connection pool. Hibernate will
> use this by default if the hibernate.c3p0.* properties are set.

Why is this not class picked up by default? Is it correct to explicitly specify `org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider`? It looks like `org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider` is the class which is picked up by default, and most of the references found in the web are regarding it, but it is not available in the above mentioned maven dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `hibernate.` from the property name, it should be:

```
<property name="connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
```

Comment: This class is not there in the classpath (not found in `hibernate-c3p0` library), so it gives me a class not found exception.